# Logged in to "-bash", not to "bash". And what is the difference?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, bashrc

I logged in via `ssh` to a remote Ubuntu-Machine.

By default I'm in a terminal called `-bash` (note the hyphen).
This bash does not load/use my ~/.bashrc.

When entering `bash` into the terminal, I get to a terminal, which also uses my .bashrc.

Now, what is the difference between `-bash` and `bash`.
Why am I logged in by default to the `-bash` version.
I executed `chsh -s /bin/bash` and restarted the machine already, which according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046192/changing-default-shell-in-linux) sets the default environment. That seems to fail.
And last but not least, if I can't change to the "normal" bash, how can I get -bash to use my .bashrc?

To illustrate my problem, here is the workflow showing console output:

```
user@machine:~$ echo $0
-bash
user@machine:~$ bash
user@machine:~$ echo $0
bash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For shells, prefixing argv[0] with a dash is a traditional way of asking it to be a "login shell" (equivalent to e.g. `bash --login`). Login shells differ from "regular" ones in that they use a different startup script (e.g. `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`) – it might show a greeting, check mail, start ssh-agent, and so on… in other words, tasks which only need to be done once.

Usually, the login shell needs to be manually told to load `.bashrc` using:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

at the end of the `~/.bash_profile` script.